# Oddity with jquery on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with IE only; FF, Chrome and Safari do not have this problem. But I think there is something in my code that IE is not liking, because I have used the same technique many times before and had no problem with IE.

Here is the problem:

I have some code that looks like this:

```
var wrongSide = $('#wrongSide');// IE cannot handle in this case (but has before)
wrongSide.dialog(
{
    autoOpen:false,
    resizable:false,
    modal:true
});
```

Then in the HTML I have an onchange=function() where the function calls some other function, which looks like this:

```
function wrongSideTrigger()
{
    wrongSide.dialog('open');
}
```

Please note I am not showing the intermediate function as it is not germane.

The above works fine as stated in FF, Safari and Chrome. However, in IE it does not work, and gives error messages to the effect that the "object does not have this property" for the line that attempts to assign the jquery selector to a var.

However, if I change the code to not use the selector vars, it works for IE. The code then looks like this:

```
$('#wrongSide').dialog(
{
    autoOpen:false,
    resizable:false,
    modal:true
});
```

and this:

```
function wrongSideTrigger()
{
//  wrongSide.dialog('open');
    $('#wrongSide').dialog('open');
}
```

then it also works in IE.

The odd thing is that I have done this technique many times and IE has had no trouble with the "jquery selector vars".

I am wondering if I have some syntax error or other which IE is not liking.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's impossible... something else is going wrong. Can you post a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine.

Javascript is victim of some pretty unexpected keywords that are not actually part of the language but I'm pretty certain that "wrongSide" is not one of them; not even on IE.

Just in case, you could try *var $wrongSide = ..... ;*

Comment: wrongSide is a var, as defined in the first code snippet. I have since adopted using a leading $ for vars that are jquery selectors, which makes this more clear. This seems to be what you are saying.

Comment: Jeffrey, a leading $ is a convention used by many jQuery programmers for variable names that point to jQuery instances.

Comment: .... Please note my terminology above. A "selector" is a string that goes in a $(...) statement to select a particular set of elements from the DOM. On execution, such a statement returns a "jQuery instance".

Comment: I tried it with the preceding $ as suggested, and as I mentioned I have adopted for all vars pointing to a jquery instance. However that did not help, and I am just going ahead with re-selecting it where needed, which is only two places, the definition of the dialog and opening it. I would typically assume it was a scope issue, except that it only affects IE. Go figure.